# Should I send parallel requests from the client, or send one request and execute them on the server in parallel?

Tags: android, node.js, retrofit

I am using retrofit on the android side and node.js on the backend side.

Retrofit allows async requests, so can I send two requests from android in parallel on the server and get the result back, or I can send one request and use caolan async to run two different requests in parallel.

Which request should I use from retrofit? Should I send parallel requests or execute them as one request in parallel?

I think the second approach is better because the first approach increases server requests which adds to the server load.

Please tell me, which approach should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your  milage may vary but in general batching saves opening and closing multiple connections.   I've had gains in performance once I started batching  multiple requests together rather than having to open and close  a connection for each request.   Best way to find out for your use case is to write a test for both and compare.

Comment: sorry but i found your answer ambiguous, can you tell me which approach worked for you first or second ??

Comment: Sorry jetlagged. Batch all requests into a single request  and then unbatch on server. Having only 1 request will minimize the amount of http overhead such as opening connection or creating/sending a header with each request .